# Backbone View - jquery events binding

Tags: backbone.js

I'm trying to understand exactly when and how jQuery events bind in a Backbone.View.
If I have a view:

`var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
events: {"click" : "handler"}
});`

Will backbone bind the click event on calling render()? On appending body? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event handlers are bound after calling initialize. Here's the [source code](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/docs/backbone.html), note the delegateEvents method:

```
var View = Backbone.View = function(options) {
    this.cid = _.uniqueId('view');
    this._configure(options || {});
    this._ensureElement();
    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    this.delegateEvents();
};
```

The delegateEvents method then has jQuery code like this:

```
this.$el.on(eventName, selector, method);
```

A specific example, listening to click events on the view element and delegating clicks on a button with a load-more class to a handler:

```
this.$el.on("click", ".load-more", function(){});
```